# How to enable touchmove in a mobile element while disabling scrolling

Tags: javascript, svg, mobile, dom-events, touch-event

I'm building an app using [svg-pencil](https://github.com/substack/svg-pencil) to allow users to draw images. Normally I would use [atrament](https://github.com/jakubfiala/atrament.js) to enable drawing on canvas, but this project requires the output to be an SVG that I can then analyze at the `<path>` level.

SVG-pencil is great but is not mobile friendly since it was developed some time ago. Using atrament as a guide, I'm trying to make it responsive to touch events as well as mouse events.

The first step was to just add the touch event listeners to the part of svg-pencil's [event registration](https://github.com/substack/svg-pencil/blob/master/index.js#L28):

```
this.listeners = {
    mousedown: function (ev) { self._onmousedown(ev) },
    mouseup: function (ev) { self._onmouseup(ev) },
    mousemove: function (ev) { self._onmousemove(ev) },
    // added these three lines
    touchstart: function (ev) { self._onmousedown(ev) },
    touchend: function (ev) { self._onmouseup(ev) },
    touchmove: function (ev) { self._onmousemove(ev) }
};
```

The trouble is that, on mobile, the default behavior for `touchmove` is to scroll the page. So I added two event listeners to the `<svg>` element that the module creates to try and prevent this:

```
var svg = p.element;

svg.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // e.preventDefault();
});

svg.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // e.preventDefault();
});
```

This successfully fires the app's `mousestart` and `mouseend` events in a mobile emulator or a real phone if you just click the drawable area, and DOES successfully disable scrolling within the svg area if you drag inside it, but the `mousemove` event registered to `touchmove` above does not fire more than once. As you can see, I tried `preventDefault` as well with no luck.

I'm not an expert in event bubbling, but somehow it appears that the `stopPropogation` call on the svg element is also canceling the event inside svg-pencil.

[Here's an example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2902359/svg-pencil/example/index.html). There's a console log on every event. It works fine in regular browswer, but you can see the problem if you select a mobile emulator in Chrome's devtools or try it in Xcode's simulator.

The full, slightly modified code is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2902359/svg-pencil.zip).

I also tried adding the `preventDefault` inside svg-pencil's event listeners with no luck.

Comment: Note: I swapped out svg-pencil for Art-SVG, which I forked to tweak some of the coordinate detection for newer mobile browsers. 
https://github.com/TimeMagazine/ArtSVG
PR submitted: https://github.com/Korilakkuma/ArtSVG/pulls
But I'd still like to understand event bubbling better if anyone is able to solve the original issue. Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve it?